# Keyword generation from product names

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding, azure-ai

I need to create an API that needs to generate keywords, similar to the ones used by SO here, from full product names.

For example, if the product name is “CompanyX Lightly Salted Cocktail Peanuts”, the main keyword would be “peanut”. Others maybe “lightly-salted” and “CompanyX”. However the most important one is “peanut”.

Has anyone built something like this? I’d appreciate some advice/pointers on how to go about this.

I’m considering Azure AI Language Service for this but I’d appreciate any suggestions. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/ai-services/ai-language/

P.S. My tech stack is .NET, C#, ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options you can consider

**1. [Key Phrase Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/key-phrase-extraction/overview)**
This is a rather straightforward option which used a readily available service via REST API to identify key words from your input text.

**2. [Custom Text Classification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/custom-text-classification/overview)**
If you have a specific set of categories/keywords that you are looking for this, this might be a better option to explicitly find the best matching "known" keywords.

**3. [Azure OpenAI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/overview)**
While this might seem overkill, you should be able to leverage OpenAI along with a custom system message (see [prompt engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/advanced-prompt-engineering)) to steer the model into identifying core keywords from the input text.

*PS: Do ensure you checking the pricing for each while evaluting these options.*

Comment: Thank you for the advice and links. Very useful indeed.